# array filter on php7

Tags: php, php-7, php-5.6

i'm working on array filter function to filter my array and remove all object of type DateTime my code was working fine on php5.6 but in php7 i get different result i'm not sure why or what changed in php7 and the best way to fix it

here code example

```
$array1 = ['one', 'two', 'three', new DateTime(), [new DateTime(), new DateTime(), new DateTime()]];

$array2 = ['one', 'two', 'three', ['four', 'five', 'six']];

$data = array_filter($array1, $callback = function (&$value) use (&$callback) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        $value = array_filter($value, $callback);
    }

    return ! $value instanceof DateTime;
});
```

if i run this code in php5.6 i get

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(3) "one" [1]=> string(3) "two" [2]=> string(5) "three" [4]=> array(0) { } }
```

it work fine by removing all object of type DateTime but if i run the code in php7 i get

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(3) "one" [1]=> string(3) "two" [2]=> string(5) "three" [4]=> array(3) { [0]=> object(DateTime)#2 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2016-06-27 18:53:11.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(11) "Asia/Riyadh" } [1]=> object(DateTime)#3 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2016-06-27 18:53:11.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(11) "Asia/Riyadh" } [2]=> object(DateTime)#4 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2016-06-27 18:53:11.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(11) "Asia/Riyadh" } } }
```

as you can see it only remove object of type DateTime only from the first level array and ignore the second level array without filtering them can you please help me to understand what changed in php7 to cause this behaviour and the best way to fix it

Comment: [***Caution**
If the array is changed from the callback function (e.g. element added, deleted or unset) the behavior of this function is undefined.*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php#refsect1-function.array-filter-notes)

Answer (score 0):

In this case it may be simpler to use a recursive function to remove the `DateTime` objects instead of `array_filter`.

```
$array1 = ['one', 'two', 'three', new DateTime(), 
              [new DateTime(), new DateTime(), new DateTime()]];

function removeDateTimes(&$x) {
    foreach ($x as $k => &$v) {
        if ($v instanceof DateTime) unset($x[$k]);
        elseif (is_array($v)) removeDateTimes($v);
    }
}

removeDateTimes($array1);
```

Because this function will modify its input array, you should make a copy of your array before using this function on it if you still need it in its original form.